# Spring controller not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I'm getting Error 404, when I try to open 'greeting.html'

Below are the files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- mapped all incoming requests to html -->
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**servlet-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rahul.controller" />

    <!-- mentions where all the JSPs are located at -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp" p:suffix=".jsp"></bean>

</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.rahul.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "hello world");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${greeting}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

My `http request` is `GET localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html`

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `http` request?

Comment: @xenteros http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/fitTrackerServlet/greeting.html` ?

Comment: @AshishPatil FitnessTracker is probably the war's name.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following refactor:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public Model sayHello() {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "hello world");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Or request:

`http://localhost:8080/fitTrackerServlet/gree‌​ting.html`

Comment: Did you check without `.html`? Did you get 404?

Comment: Still a no. Checked with & without .html: 'http://localhost:8080/greeting' & 'http://localhost:8080/greeting.html'

Comment: @reiley try the current answer

Comment: found it ... it was missing '/' from `p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"`. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Nice. Cool that you've found the solution.